# Problema al modificar el valor de JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

intento hacer por cuenta propia una calculadora simple y sencilla, pero me encuentro con un problema al intentar que, al presionar un boton se cambie el valor del JTextField.

Aquí el codigo:

Clase Frame:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{

public Frame(){
    setTitle("Calculadora...");
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(new PanelResultado(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(new PanelOperaciones(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Clase PanelResultado (Aquí es donde se ingresan los valores)

```
class PanelResultado extends JPanel{
     private JTextField res = null;

    public PanelResultado() {
       setLayout(new BorderLayout());

       res = new JTextField("0");
       res.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
       res.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
       res.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
       res.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));
       res.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
       res.setEditable(false);
       add(res);
   }

   public JTextField getRes() {
       return res;
   }

   public void setRes(String texto) {
       this.res.setText(texto);
   }
 }
```

Clase PanelOperaciones (Son los botones de los numeros y operadores)

```
class PanelOperaciones extends JPanel{

    private JButton b1 = null;
    private PanelResultado panel;

    public PanelOperaciones() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        agregarBoton("9");
        agregarBoton("8");
        agregarBoton("7");
        agregarBoton("( / )");

        agregarBoton("6");
        agregarBoton("5");
        agregarBoton("4");
        agregarBoton("( * )");

        agregarBoton("3");
        agregarBoton("2");
        agregarBoton("1");
        agregarBoton("( + )");

        agregarBoton("0");
        agregarBoton("Limpiar");
        agregarBoton("( = )");
        agregarBoton("( - )");

        panel = new PanelResultado();
    }

    private void agregarBoton(String n) {
        b1 = new JButton(n);
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        b1.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN, 15));

        add(b1);

        ejecutar();
    }

    void ejecutar() {
        ActionListener oyente = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                panel.setRes("cambiando..");
            }
        };
        b1.addActionListener(oyente);
    }  
}
```

Bueno, aquí es la clase donde intento hacer lo que comenté al inicio y no me funciona. También probé con una clase aparte donde esta implementaba a ActionListener, y de igual forma no me funciona... aclarar que todo está en un mismo archivo y que importa lo necesario para que funcione, el IDE no me marca ningun error, así que no es nada de eso.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Hay 2 instancias de `PanelResultado`, cuando se accione algún botón pondrá el texto en el campo de la primera instancia que en la GUI está ubicada gráficamente debajo del `JTextField` de esa segunda instancia, de allí el efecto de como si no pasara nada, el segundo `JTextField` te esta tapando el primero que instanciaste, me explico?

Comment: Ohh.. sí, te entendí, había olvidado que creaba una nueva instancia.. y cómo podría solucionar este problema para hacer lo que busco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución tentativa, partiendo de la base de no cambiar la estructura general del código:

Un único objeto en la clase donde se lanza la app, `Frame`:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    private PanelResultado PR = new PanelResultado();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Frame();
    }

    public Frame() {
      // ....

      /*En vez de:
      add(new PanelResultado(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(new PanelOperaciones(), BorderLayout.CENTER);*/

      add(PR, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(new PanelOperaciones(PR), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      //...
    }
}
```

Ello logicamente implica que `PanelOperaciones` debe recibir el panel `PanelResultado`

```
class PanelOperaciones extends JPanel {
  private PanelResultado panel;
  //...

  public PanelOperaciones( PanelResultado panel ) {
    //...

    this.panel = panel;

    //...
  }
}
```

En el listener del metodo `ejecutar()` ahora el `panel` es la instancia del unico objeto que se creó en `Frame`:

```
void ejecutar() {
  ActionListener oyente = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      //panel.setRes("cambiando..");
      panel.setRes( panel.getRes().getText() + arg0.getActionCommand() );
    }
  };
  b1.addActionListener(oyente);
}
```

Ahora el flujo de ejecución es distinto.

Comment: Qué buena solucion man, muchas gracias. Sabes, yo lo había arreglado haciendo estático el metodo que devuelve el JTextField, para así usarlo en la otra clase. Hmm, una consulta. Mi duda (la del tema), lo publique en otro lado y alguien (el unico) me dijo que debía repasar OOP, tu crees lo mismo?

No sé porq tal respuesta y todo "seca".. quizás porque le dije que ya había arreglado el problema con static, y él no pudo, me dijo eso o no sé.. jajajaa en fin.... espero consejos, aun comienzo en el mundo de Java.

Gracias.